# Translation workbench backup?

Tags: translation-workbench, managed-package

I am new to using the translation workbench. I am trying to setup translation workbench for the installed packages in our org for end users. Is there a way we can back up the workbench data in case something goes wrong in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

you can do that with ant (Force.com migration tool).

Add this to your package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Translations</name>
</types>
```